# Phpmyadmin is not showing all tables in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, centos

I have been running a website from home for a few months now and suddenly phpmyadmin is not showing me all the tables in the mysql database.

Here is a screenshot 1:
[image: I have marked sensitive information with black, Please Ignore]

I thought the database could be corrupt or maybe someone has executed some bad sql code so I deleted the database and tried to restore from a date that I knew was working and the same thing happened. So I built a new server thinking something in phpmyadmin could be corrupt but now I am facing the same issue on the new server.

I tried manually creating the database but after so many tables have been created the same thing happens.

As you can see in the screenshot 1 on the left side it stops after customcars but then in the middle in continues to downloads. There should be more tables but they will not show up.

I have ran a script to check if they exist and they do but I just cannot access them on phpmyadmin

I have tried importing the database with a .sql file and still no luck.

Sometimes it evan looks like this
[image: Screenshot 2]

Notice the way the customcars on the left is missing and so is the X in the middle for downloads.

My Operating System Is Centos 6, 
Mysql Version 5.1.73,
Phpmyadmin 2.11.11.3

Thank you for reading and I hope someone out there has had the same issue so I can fix this asap :)

Comment: may not be related, but that is quite an old version of phpmyadmin

Comment: @dagon Thank You for pointing that out, I will upgrade after work tomorrow.

Comment: @slier Yes I login as root, Is this bad from a security point of view? Also could logging in as root cause any issues?

Comment: @ShaneHodson cehck ur table permission, sometime u have mess up ur table permission

Comment: Definitely try an updated version. It looks (especially in your second picture) like the page isn't fully loading, does it take a long time to display even this much? Check your webserver error logs for hints. This is not in any way a large number of tables so I wonder if your MySQL server is under heavy load. Is this a hosted environment or on your own computer?

Comment: I am running VMware ESXI with windows server 2012 running in a hosted environment. I updated the phpmyadmin but it was a lot of messing around in centos and evan after the upgrade it failed to work. I think the problem could be at a hypervisor level because ever since the ESXI licence expired and I went to the free version it has started acting strange. The hypervisor will not shutdown and that could explain why it wont work on a new virtual server. I will reinstall the hypervisor and let uses know how i get on :)

Answer (score 12):

You might want to check that `Settings > Navigation Panel > Maximum items in branch` is not set to a low number. http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxNavigationItems

Comment: Thank you for the url. This seems to be for the latest version of phpmyadmin but I will upgrade tomorrow and let uses know if it done the job!

Comment: The option should be there for your version aswell. Just click the home/house button, hit settings and then _Navigation Panel_.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I found an eye symbol next to my database name in the left column. When I cliked on the eye symbol I had the option to unhide the missing table. I have no idea how I managed to hide this table but this solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks so much. In my case it's a bulb icon. The disappearance might have happened because I clicked on the right of the table name by mistake, one day. If your pointer is over a table name, such a grayed bulb appears and allows you to hide the table name. Nice feature but not for clumsy people obviously.

Comment: yes. I have since found this feature because I managed to accidentally hide another table.

Comment: I had this problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You might accidentally hide any table by clicking eye on PhpMyadmin. Click the eye icon then it appears a pop up to show the hidden table.